# How to update a certain column with large number of rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We are using the following query to set a certain field to null in a table having 2 million rows. Is there a faster way to do this using the ActiveRecord API. Right now it takes 2-3 minutes to return from this call.

```
Foo.update_all(:bar => nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. This will just execute very straightforward SQL:

```
UPDATE foos SET bar = NULL
```

No idea how to utilize the ActiveRecord API to make *that* faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, another way to do what you want.

```
ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN bar;
```

and then,

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar INT(10) DEFAULT NULL;
```